# Tell what protractor's waitForAngular is stuck on?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Is there any way to determine what Protractor's `browser.waitForAngular()` is getting stuck on?

My Protractor test basically loads the page, clicks on an element, and then waits for a new page to load. I'm getting the *"Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds,"* error; however, I don't use `$timeout`, and can see that there are no outstanding http requests in my browser's Developer Console.

I can manually reproduce the same steps as my test in my browser, and run

```
angular.getTestability(document.body)
    .whenStable(function() {console.log("holla")})
```

and see that the page is, in fact, stable within 1 second of loading.

If I write a protractor test that loads the first page, and then uses `browser.get('index.html#second-page')`, the test passes.

I am aware that I can set `ignoreSerialization` on Protractor, but honestly, I'd rather not, because I'm concerned that there is some insidious bug in my Angular project. Are there any steps I can take to get a deeper look at what's going on in Protractor?

Comment: Just to check...the next page that loads is angular or non-angular?

Comment: Both pages are angular. I'm using UI-Router, so I'm not actually loading another page - it's just changing the state of my application by setting the hash portion of the URL.

Comment: A coworker found something waiting on a JavaScript timeout (rather than angular $timeout), which was holding up Protractor. I think the question is still valid, though; in a complicated application, is there any way to track down the cause of Angular instability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a setTimeout in your code, protractor will not be able to synchronize. Consider using $interval instead.